# Image resolution and specs for using in an android mobile app for balanced efficiency and quality

Tags: android, flutter, image

Right now, I am developing a mobile physics learning app for android using Flutter, and have quite an amount of images to use in the app.

Sometimes I find that when freshly opening a new screen I still can see a split second where the image is loading. I am wondering **how I can speed the process of loading the images, what is the best resolution, size and pixel density to achieve the perfect balance between speed and quality.**
Also, maybe there is a way in flutter to open the new screen (route) only after everything has finished loading (although that may not look the best compared to the instant opening of a new article).

Right now I am using `.png` files, which most of the time do not cover the whole screen.

Comment: Post the code showing how you're doing it now, or we can't see if our answer is going to be an improvement